# Цикл добавляет только последний проход и затирает предыдущие

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива

```
dataArr = [[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]];
colors = ['red','green','blue'];
```

И функция, в которую они идут в качестве аргументов.

```
function makeDataArrays(dataObj,colors) {
    var a = {}; var b = [];
    for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
        a.color=colors[i];
        a.data=dataObj[i];
        b.push(a);
    }
    return b;
}

newArr = makeDataArrays(dataArr, colors);
```

В итоге функция вернет массив объектов. Все объекты будут одинаковы и равны последней итерации. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему? Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объекты в массиве у вас не просто равны, это - **один и тот же объект**

Создавайте новый объект на каждой итерации - и будет вам счастье

Comment: @Skotinin То есть перенесите код `var a = {};` внутрь цикла.

Comment: На первом проходе присваиваем значения свойствам, записываем его массив. На втором проходе изменяем значения свойств и записываем измененный объект в массив и тд.. Разве не так работает?

Comment: @Skotinin Вы изменяете свойства того же самого объекта и заносите его в массив еще раз. Массив содержит ссылки, которые указывают на один и тот же объект `a`.